# Drupal add content not showing correct content types

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am building a site on Drupal 7 and recently when I went into add content, not all of my content types were listed. Thinking it might be related to the recently installed webform module, I disabled the module and removed the webform content type (which was one that was showing up under add content). These changes made no difference. While the webform content isn't there any more, the other content types are still not showing up. I can manually get to the page to add the missing content types by entering the URL /node/add/missing-content-type-name. There must be some corruption in the database that is not aggregating all the content types on the add content page. How do I fix this?

Comment: Its look like a problem with menu system, have tried to clear all caches ?

Comment: Yes, I cleared all caches multiple times and it didn't make a difference. I have still not found a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer here: http://drupal.org/node/1291336. The menu items were disabled and needed to be reenabled under the navigation menu.